# How to Remove duplicate dropdown option elements with same value

Tags: jquery

How can I remove duplicate values -> drop down option elements?
I have the following HTML:

```
<option value="">All Servers</option>
<option value="com">http://smiles.com</option>
<option value="in">http://3smiles.com</option>
<option value="com">http://desk.com</option>
<option value="in">http://france24.com</option>
```

from the above I have to remove repeated values `com` and `in`, so my expected output should be like:

```
<option value="">All Servers</option>
<option value="com">http://smiles.com</option>
<option value="in">http://3smiles.com</option>
```

How to do it using jQuery?

Comment: How are the duplicates getting there in the first place?

Comment: `value=com` and `value=in` are getting as server response

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (to target sibling `option` elements), and [Attribute Equals Selector `[attr=""]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
$(".select option").each(function() {
  $(this).siblings('[value="'+ this.value +'"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="com">.com 1</option>
  <option value="net">.net 1</option>
  <option value="com">.com 2</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
  <option value="net">.net 2</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
</select>
```

(works also for multiple `.select` on the same page)
<sup>I added a class `.select` to the `<select>` element to be more selector-specific</sup>

**How it works**:
while `option`s are accessed one by one (by `.val()`) - lookup for `.sibling()` `option`s that have the same `"[value='"+ this.value +"']"` and [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) them.

Comment: Only one problem to correct here. Add quotes for values please or else breaks ```$(this).siblings("[value='"+ this.value+"']").remove();```

Comment: This works when you start selecting options from scratch, but when form already has fields that are pre-selected (edit_form) the disabling doesn't kick in. only from the 2+ attemp it works. Do you know how I can make it so that this checks the pre-filled fields as well?

Comment: @morinx the question was how to remove duplicate `option` elements  (duplicate values) from a `select` - so I'm not following your request/issue...

Comment: I understand, this is a very specific case of this issue. I have explained the situation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892320/dropdown-option-validation-for-pre-filled-select-fields-with-jquery

Comment: I think, you should add `return val;` after removing - otherwise all options values becomes empty.

Comment: This code will break for values containing apostrophe(s)

Answer (score 14):

The correct solution will be is to not to allow the server to have duplicate values....

try

```
var map = {};
$('select option').each(function () {
    if (map[this.value]) {
        $(this).remove()
    }
    map[this.value] = true;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YCE5r/)

Answer (score 7):

use this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var usedNames = {};
    $("select > option").each(function () {
        if (usedNames[this.value]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedNames[this.value] = this.text;
        }
    });
});
```

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/aelor/aspMT/

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<select class="something">
<option value="">All Servers</option>
<option value="com">http://smiles.com</option>
<option value="in">http://3smiles.com</option>
<option value="com">http://desk.com</option>
<option value="in">http://france24.com</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var seen = {};
jQuery('.something').children().each(function() {
    var txt = jQuery(this).attr('value');
    if (seen[txt]) {
        jQuery(this).remove();
    } else {
        seen[txt] = true;
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m37Kg/1/)</kbd>

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but this did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but something like this should work

```
var values = new Array();
$('#YourSelect').children('option').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  if (values.indexOf(text) === -1) {
    values.push(text);
  } else {
    //  Its a duplicate
    $(this).remove()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/yayTm/2/

```
var exist = {};
$('select > option').each(function() {
    if (exist[$(this).val()]){
        $(this).remove();
    }else{
        exist[$(this).val()] = true;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

# This is other quick option  iterating options, counting the duplicates and remove when are more than one#

```
var opt = $("select[title='Country'] option");              
$.each(opt, function (key, value) {                 
  var len = $("select[title='Country'] option:contains(" + value.text + ")").length;
  if (len > 1)                   
     {
     value.remove();
     }   
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove options with duplicate values.

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
        var a = new Array();
        $("#selectID").children("option").each(function(x){
            test = false;
            b = a[x] = $(this).val();
            for (i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
                if (b ==a[i]) test =true;
            }
            if (test) $(this).remove();
        })
    });
```