# Hide option if its value is equal to another option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox, html-select

I'm trying to write some code to hide an `<option>` if its value is equal to the value of the first  (which is dynamic and retrieved with php)
This is the code:

```
<select onChange="this.form.submit()" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" class="input-text qty qtySelect" >
    <option value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" class="input-text qty qtySelected" ><?php echo $this->getQty() ?></option>
    <option value="1" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" data-qty="1" class="input-text qty notSelected" label="1" ><span>1</span></option>
    <option value="2" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" data-qty="2" class="input-text qty notSelected" label="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" data-qty="3" class="input-text qty notSelected" label="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
$j('.qtySelect').change(function(){
    if(('.qtySelected').val() == ('.notSelected').val())
    { 
        $j('.notSelected').hide();
    }
});
```

But this didn't work. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: `if(('.qtySelected').val() == ('.notSelected').val())` should be `if($j('.qtySelected').val() == $j('.notSelected').val())`

Comment: Just use `$j('.notSelected[value='+ this.value +']').hide();` in `change-handler`

Comment: Here is the awnser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729456/how-to-remove-duplicate-dropdown-option-elements-with-same-value#answer-23729617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will hide all options which are duplicated, Try:

```js
$(".qtySelect option").each(function(){
    $(this).siblings("[value='"+ this.value+"']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cart[0][qty]" class="input-text qty qtySelect" >
    <option value="1" name="cart[1[qty]" class="input-text qty qtySelected" >1</option>
    <option value="1" name="cart[1][qty]" data-qty="1" class="input-text qty notSelected" label="1" ><span>1</span></option>
    <option value="2" name="cart[3[qty]" data-qty="2" class="input-text qty notSelected" label="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" name="cart[4][qty]" data-qty="3" class="input-text qty notSelected" label="3">3</option>
</select>
```