# Dropdown option validation for pre-filled select fields with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this JQuery piece to prevent selection of dropdown options that are already selected in another field.

```
    var $coll = $( 'select[name$="service"]' ).on( 'change', function () {
        $coll.each(function () {
              var val = this.value;
              if ( val === 'original' ) return;
              $coll.not( this ).children( '[value="' + val + '"]' ).prop( 'disabled', true );
        });
    });
```

The problem is that this only works when you start selection from scratch (empty form).
When I have a form that has fields with pre-selected options, the function only kicks in after the second attempt.

Do you know how I can change this to check for pre-filled fields as well?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] (HTML and stuff...)

Comment: Why do you `$coll.children().prop( 'disabled', false );` in the first place?

Comment: you are right, that line is unnecessary, but was not related to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to `.trigger("change")` after document ready, so that the validation begins before the first selection.