# Is it possible to delete or disable or hide a drop-down option of select attribute in angular4

Tags: angular, html-select, dropdown

I have written my code in angular4 and i want to hide or disable a repetitive option that appears in the dropdown. Can you please let me know the possible way to hide it .

I tried implementing codes from -

[How to Remove duplicate dropdown option elements with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729456/how-to-remove-duplicate-dropdown-option-elements-with-same-value)

[image]

**assign.component.ts**

```
  import * as $ from 'jquery';
  import { JQuery } from 'jquery';


   export class AssignComponent implements OnInit {

   seen = {};

  getRolesList() {
   var url = config.url;
   var port = config.port;
    this.http.post("http:....
   .map(result => this.rolesList = result.json())
   .subscribe((res: Response) => {


 JQuery('.updateMappingUserRole').children().each(function() {
  var txt = JQuery(this).attr('value');
  if (this.seen[txt]) {
      JQuery(this).remove();
  } else {
      this.seen[txt] = true;
  }
  });

  }
```

***assign.component.ts***

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="role"> Role: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="updateMappingUserRole"

    [formControl]=
     "updateMappingRoleForm.controls['updateMappingUserRole']"
            [(ngModel)]="updateMappingUserRole" 
      (change)="getRoleID(updateMappingUserRole)" id="role">
            <option  > {{updateMappingUserRole}}</option>
              <option  *ngFor="let i of rolesList">{{i.ROLE_CD}} 
              </option>

              </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
.map(result => this.removeDuplicates(result.json(), this.rolesList));

removeDuplicates(json: any[], destination: any[]) {
  destination = json.reduce((p, n) => {
    // If role already in array, don't push
    if (!p.includes(n)) { p.push(n); }
    return p;
  }, []);
}
```

This function will transform your array returned by the HTTP call with the `reduce` function.

#### EDIT : How `reduce` works ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce))

For newcomers in Javascript, or people not knowing the `reduce` function :

`reduce` is a function that will iterate over the array and transform it. Its signature is

```
reduce(callback(previousElement, nextElement, currentIndex, arr), startingValue);
```

Let's use an example : transform an array of numbers into their square values.

```js
const initial = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const transformed = initial.reduce((p, n) => {
  p.push(n * n);
  return p;
}, []); // Will give [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Now let's break it down :

On the first iteration, we are on the first item of the array : 1.

The initial value given to the `reduce` function is an empty array.
In the callback, this will give

```
p = [], n = 1
```

So, we push the square value of 1 into the array, then return the array (mandatory).

The next iteration comes : the values of the callback are

```
p = [1], n = 2
```

We do the same process, and on the third and fourth iterations, we will have this

```
3 : p = [1, 4], n = 3
4 : p = [1, 4, 9], n = 4
```

Once the function is finished (`nextElement` has no more value to take), it returns the last value of `previousElement`, which is the transformed array.

Comment: `reduce` is somewhere new to me, nice :)

Comment: I am getting the following errors - Property 'removeDuplicates' does not exist on type 'AssignComponent'.Cannot find name 'destination'......do we need to add any library or href link

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava `removeDuplicates` is supposed to be a function of your component, you probably wrote it somewhere else (probably in another function). I thought you would understand that. And no, you don't need libraries.

Comment: @PardeepJain do you want a quick explanation or you're good with the documentation ?

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava I think you just copied and paste as it is after `.map` function, you need to add it as a function in your component file. Then this should work

Comment: @trichetriche If you can add more explanation it would be great for others as well

Comment: @PardeepJain done, see if your understand, and if not, make a feedback !

Comment: @triche ... i have placed the removeDuplicates method else where in the component ... and  i wrote this like this  --> .map(result => this.removeDuplicates(result.json(), this.rolesList )=result.json())
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {...}  but getting the error  --> The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access...

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava where do you see `.map(result => this.removeDuplicates(result.json(), this.rolesList )=result.json())` written in my answer ? You simply have to copy/paste my syntax ...

Comment: @ Triche ... i only get a single value in the drop-down. The drop-down list has disappeared ... don't you think we need subscribe also ?

Comment: Look, I can't help you if I'm blind. Please make a [mcve] on stackblitz, where you mock your data. Because right now, all I can see is that you don't fully understand Angular, and if you create errors in your code, I can't know it.

Comment: if i include subscribe i get this error -Argument of type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response'.

Comment: @trichetriche Great, Appreciate it !! I wish I could upvote your answer twice :P