# How to get the value of a dynamically created option and send to/receive it on nodejs?

Tags: jquery, node.js

**Edit:** Solved. Turns out, I'm just dumb. As pointed out on the comments the issue was here:

```
//The area where I deal with duplicates
$("#grupoSelected option").val(...)
```

.val() was the problema. Just change it to this: (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729456/how-to-remove-duplicate-dropdown-option-elements-with-same-value/23729505), second answer)

```
let map = {};
$("select option").each(function () {
 if(map[this.value]) {
   $(this).remove();
 }
 map[this.value] = true;
});
```

---

I've tried everything I could find and not a single one of them worked. I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Heads up, I barely know what I'm doing.

What I want  to know is how the hell do I get the value from the options generated by jquery at grupoSelected and hospitalSelected below.

I have these two selects:

```
<select name="grupoSelected" id="grupoSelected" class="select form-control floating" required>
    <option value=""> -- selecione um grupo -- </option>
</select>

<select name="hospitalSelected" id="hospitalSelected" class="select form-control floating" required>
  <option hidden disabled selected value> -- selecione um hospital -- </option>
</select>
```

That gets populated by a ajax post/get request and jquery below

Group (that gets defined by the class picked on a previous select):

```
$("#turmaSelected").on('change', function () {
    let turmaSelected = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/info/turma',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { turma: turmaSelected },
      success: function (data) {
        let grupo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $(grupo).each((i, e) => {
          $('#grupoSelected').append(`<option value="${e.id}"> ${e.nome_grupo} </option>`)

          //$('<option>').attr(e.id).text(e.nome_grupo).appendTo('#grupoSelected');
        });
        
        // This removes any duplicate entry since different classes can have the same group name
        $("#grupoSelected option").val(function (id, val) {
          $(this).siblings('[value="' + val + '"]').remove();
        });

      },
      error: function (error) {
        if (error.message === undefined || error === "") {
          $("#error_alert").show();
          $('#error_alert').text('Nenhum grupo foi encontrado.');
        }
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
      }
    });
  });
```

Hospital:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/info/hospital',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
      let hospital = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

      $(hospital).each((i, e) => {
        $("#hospitalSelected").append(`<option value='${hospital[i].nome_hospital}'>${hospital[i].nome_hospital}</option>`);
      });

      $("#hospitalSelected option").val(function (idx, val) {
        $(this).siblings('[value="' + val + '"]').remove();
      });

    },
    error: function (error) {
      if (error.message === undefined || error === "") {
        $("#error_alert").show();
        $('#error_alert').text('Nenhum hospital foi encontrado.');
      }
      console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  });
```

Even in the html it doesn't seem to assign the value to the option and whenever I press submit and it gets sent to the backend, all I get back is this:

```
{
  turmaSelected: 'md9',
  grupoSelected: '',
  discSelected: 'clinicaMedica',
  hospitalSelected: '',
  rodizio_numero: '1',
  data_inicio: '07/09/2021',
  data_fim: '07/09/2021'
}
```

And these two: **grupoSelected** and **hospitalSelected** have both their option generated dynamically by jquery.

I'm using express, ejs, sequelize, nodejs, postgresql and bootstrap 4 (because the template I'm using had this version and unfortunately it's a pain to update)

Relevant part from controller:

```
const {
      turmaSelected,
      grupoSelected,
      discSelected,
      hospitalSelected,
      rodizio_numero,
      data_inicio,
      data_fim,
    } = req.body;
```

Relevant parts from app:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ extended: true }));
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `$("#grupoSelected option").val(...)`    I don't think you want to use `.val()` here, especially since you aren't returning a value. You're essentially nuking all your `<option>` values

Comment: Never have I felt so stupid! Turns out it was exactly that, I change it to ".each" and it did start receiving data normally. The only issue now is that i'm back at trying to get rid of duplicates. 

Do you know a way I could do that?

Comment: Actually, there's no need anymore. I've found a way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729456/how-to-remove-duplicate-dropdown-option-elements-with-same-value/23729505 The second answer worked much better and felt much clearer to me